# WSO2 without subscription

Tags: wso2

Im currently evaluating different middleware and WSO2 is coming up in the top as it has almost all feature we need to automate and integrate business processes, without need for wiring many different tools together: BPM, IM, Forms creation, API Management, BPMN runtime, etc. However, we are a relatively small company and I cant justify the costs of acquiring a subscription at the moment. Question is, is there anyone using WSO2 without subscription and just doing support/maintenance themselves on a production environment? Any hurdles to be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

> is there anyone using WSO2 without subscription

You can use them free as an open-source product without any subscription. There are many companies doing so.

> Any hurdles to be aware of?

Part of the subscription service WSO2 issues patches and security updates, you should follow and apply the updates yourself (well, nothing forces you to do so, but I'd recommend to do it)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the number of questions we can see on Stack Overflow, there seem to be many companies that are using the free and open-source version of WSO2 products.